# getting Deep into Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

> The better you understand what you are doing, the better you will do it.

I want to get Deep into Flex . I did some simple Event-Handling and 
The better you understand what you are doing, the better you will do it.

**But** i have i big question:

What does the Compiler do ?!
What happens with the MXML file ?

lets say we have a simple code ( code from blogflexexamples):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/27/changing-the-flex-colorpicker-controls-swatch-panel-background-color/ -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="top"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Style>
        .myColorPicker {
            swatchPanelStyleName: myCustomSwatchPanelStyleName;
        }

        .myCustomSwatchPanelStyleName {
            backgroundColor: haloBlue;
        }
    </mx:Style>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ColorPickerEvent;

            private function backgroundColor_change(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
                var cssObj:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".myCustomSwatchPanelStyleName");
                cssObj.setStyle("backgroundColor", evt.color);

                colorPicker.open();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Form styleName="plain">
            <mx:FormItem label="backgroundColor:">
                <mx:ColorPicker change="backgroundColor_change(event);" />
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:ColorPicker id="colorPicker"
            styleName="myColorPicker"
            editable="false" />

</mx:Application>
```

does this generate an Actionscript file ?
and if it does : Can i see the the .as file ( like preprocessor in C++ )?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. MXML is translated into an ActionScript class. You can see the generated as code by adding -keep-generated-actionscript switch to the Additional compiler arguments in Project properties->Flex compiler.

Comment: Take a look at Adobe Developer Connection - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/coding_with_mxml_and_actionscript/

Answer (score 2):

Another good reference is the recently-released book Developing Flex 4 Components by Mike Jones. It mentions the compilation of MXML to Actionscript on page 4 and provides a solid grounding in how Flex components work.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are some good places to digg deep into the Flex Compiler:

- [Diving in the Data Binding Waters](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/diving-in-the-data-binding-waters-by-michael-labriola/) (with [Presentation Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/diving-in-the-flex-data-binding-waters-presentation)) - Shows how [Bindable] is converted into actionscript
- [Flex SDK Compiler Source Code](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/modules/compiler/src/java/flex2/compiler/)
- [Flex 3 Compiler Design](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+3+Compiler+Design)
- [Flex Mojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/index.html) (with [Source SVN](http://svn.sonatype.org/flexmojos/trunk/)) - Awesome code customizing how the compiler processes things.
- [Clement Wong's Blog](http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/flex-compiler-shell-fcsh/) - He was the previous leading Flex Compiler Engineer, points to some good resources.
- [Customizing Metadata Processing with Flex 4 Custom Compiler Extensions](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2009/08/flex_compiler_e.htm) - New resources for the Compiler